# Ajax GET request is success but the variable not set

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
this.encryptUserObject = function(userObj){
 var newpassword = [];
 var urlPost = '';
 console.log(password);
 urlPost = 'http:mysite.com/root/custome.svc/Encrypts'+ '/?' + "Phrase=test";
 $.ajax({
    url:urlPost,
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response){

        return response;
    },
    error:function(res){
        console.log("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
    }
 });
}
```

This is one of method in my class. `cosole.log` in `success` method is working, showing result (new password in encryption text), but the `newpassword` print in console `$.ajax` no value.

Any idea what could be causing this.

Comment: That should not even work, it has a syntax error. Missing one quote here `urlPost = 'http:mysite.com/root/custome.svc/Encrypts+ '/?' + "Phrase=test";` after `Enrypts`

Comment: The syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow should give you a clue

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. Your last console.log is executed long before success handler is executed, and newpassword is set. newpassword processing shouldonly be done as part of your success handler (or done() function)

Comment: No, it was my bad typo here. Updated!

Comment: @jbl so should I change from success() to done()?

Comment: that's not necessary. It should just improve readability. Anyway, the key point is that newpassword will only be available in success handler (or equivalent) . The thing you must remember here is that you have to think in terms of asynchronous execution.

Comment: So how could I return that `newpassword` in my function?

Comment: Followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success, and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log is running before ajax success. To check the variable, assign it to global scope(only for testing):

```
this.encryptUserObject = function(userObj){
 var newpassword = [];
 var urlPost = '';
 console.log(password);
 urlPost = 'http:mysite.com/root/custome.svc/Encrypts'+ '/?' + "Phrase=test";
 $.ajax({
    url:urlPost,
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response){
        window.newpassword = response; //here is update
        console.log(response);
    },
    error:function(res){
        console.log("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
    }
 });
 //console.log("this is ur new password " + newpassword);
}
```

Then you can type in browser console:

```
window.newpassword
```

If you want to notify user about password, do it in `success` method, not outside!

Comment: I don't want to notify it to user dear! But I want to return it in my function. `return()` also in the same scope as `console.log` above.

Comment: @Domo if your process includes some asynchronous behavior, then the whole process becomes asynchronous. You must think asynchronous, in terms of callback. Your function should be passed a handler function that you would invoke in the success handler, passing the newly obtained newpassword as argument

Answer (score 0):

console logging is executed way before ajax success, if you want to use the password after it is set, just pass it as an argument to a function inside sucess callback

```
this.encryptUserObject = function(userObj){
 var newpassword = [];
 var urlPost = 'http:mysite.com/root/custome.svc/Encrypts'+ '/?' + "Phrase=test";
 newpassword = $.ajax({
    url:urlPost,
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response){

        return response;
    },
    error:function(res){
        console.log("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
    }
 });
 console.log(newpassword);
}
```

Comment: But when I use `return newpassword;`, it still got the same problem.

Comment: where and why would you use return ? or better asked, where do you want to return it ?

Comment: I've updated the question (added return newpassword;). I put the return because I want to take `newpassword` value to use in another place like `var newpwd  = obj.encryptUserObject(_userobj);`

Comment: You are still facing the same problem that you return it before the ajax-call is successfull, just put "return newpassword" to the success-function and youre done, cheers. ...there are thousand ways

Comment: I added `return` in `success` but it still got the same problem.

Comment: `console.log(newpassword);` in your answer print out : `Object { readyState=1, getResponseHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}` and the value get from return statement still `undefined`